# How to implement RSU application in inet project

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

i'm using inet and veins_inet to implement vanet simulation i need an RSU in my simulation so i added RSU veins module to my network and for the application a created a module that inherits from `VeinsInetApplicationBase` but when i run the simulation i have the following error :

```
Submodule appl: No module type named 'rsuApp' found that implements module interface org.car2x.veins.base.modules.IBaseApplLayer (not in the loaded NED files?) -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) Network.rsu[0] (id=6), during network setup
```

i tried with an application module inherited from `DemoBaseApplLayer` but it doesn't work either

Comment: What’s giving you problems? Do you need help interpreting the error message?

Comment: i want to know how i can implement the application of the RSU in my inet simulation

Answer (score 2):

You can treat an RSU like a car that does not move: instantiate a Car manually in your simulation and set its mobility to StationaryMobility.

Comment: i did the following but i dont know if i'm right : in the network.ned i added in the submodules : ``` rsu[1] : VeinsInetCar;``` in the omnetpp: *.rsu[*].app[0].typename ="rsuApp" *.rsu[*].mobility.typename = "StationaryMobility" but when i run the simulation i have the following error : ``` A runtime error occurred: No such interface 'wlan' -- in module (inet::HostAutoConfigurator) Network.rsu[0].ifConfig (id=25), during network initialization ```

Comment: Just changing mobility to stationary doesn't help. VeinsInetBaseApplication for the rsu need to be changed.